# ROW() returns wrong row in array in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

With this code

```
={"Row 1 is row "&ROW();"Row 2 is row "&ROW()}
```

I get this

```
Row 1 is row 1
Row 2 is row 1
```

I assume this is because ROW() returns the row the formula is actually input to. How do I get the correct row number in an array?

EDIT:

What I actually have is this

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({
TEXT(DATE(2022,1,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,1,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,1,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,2,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,2,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,2,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,3,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,3,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,3,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,4,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,4,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,4,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,5,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,5,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,5,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,6,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,6,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,6,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,7,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,7,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,7,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,8,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,8,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,8,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,9,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,9,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,9,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,10,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,10,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,10,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,11,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,11,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,11,1),0)))));
TEXT(DATE(2022,12,1),"MMMM");ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(2022,12,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2022,12,1),0)))))},379,1)
```

This lists all the days of the year with one line added for the month's name. Next to it I have numbers corresponding to each day, and I want to sum all the numbers in each month using the same arrayformula. The problem is that some years are leapyears, so february is dynamic and I need ROW() to tell me what row march starts on but it seems now I need to rethink that formula.

Comment: Could you rollback your edit and ask a new question with sample input and output as  tables/images? I think it's answerable. But, Changing goal posts completely isn't fair to the existing answer. Also, your question will get increased exposure on a new question

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved when you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: As I read your EDIT and your question, they don't match. The input is clear. But more clarity is needed on what exactly is desired.  [(Minimal) examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be used. And indeed, if the question changes completely, a different question should be asked.

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
={"Row 1 is row "&ROW();"Row 2 is row "&ROW()+1}
```

or:

```
={"Row 1 is row "&ROW(A1);"Row 2 is row "&ROW(A2)}
```

but its better this way:

```
=INDEX({"Row "&ROW(A1:A2)&" is row "&ROW(A1:A2)})
```

Comment: The arrays are dynamic in the real example, using SEQUENCE() to make each ROW() end up on different rows. So this won't work.

Comment: @LinusFornstedt ROW() will always return the current row where you input the formula. it does not work with arrays. if this is something that should be dynamic your best option is to use +1 like shown in first formula

Comment: @LinusFornstedt For the provided formula in your question, `ROW()+1` will work.

Comment: I updated my question but I wager it will no longer be answerable. I tried simplifying it down to it's core problem but I guess that wasn't the problem after all.

Comment: @LinusFornstedt can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output? checking your long formula it looks like its overkilled several times